# Joystick control for camera only works when button pressed

Tags: unity, controllers

I'm trying to use a controller that has a joystick. I'd like to move the camera when the player moves the joystick. The joystick also has a button. So far I'm only seeing the camera move when the button is pressed. How can I get the camera to move even when the button is not pressed?

I added the part that handles the movement, and yes I know that the method `GetButtonDown` is incorrect for what i'm asking to do, but I don't see any other functions that handles the joystick movements.

```
protected virtual void UpdateObject(  SixenseInput.Controller controller )
{

    z += 0.5f;
    if (controller.GetButtonDown (SixenseButtons.JOYSTICK)) {
        m_initialPosition += new Vector3(0.0f,0.0f,z);
        this.gameObject.transform.position = m_initialPosition;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are literally getting the Joystick button state and only moving if it's pressed...

```
if (controller.GetButtonDown (SixenseButtons.JOYSTICK)) {
```

Just remove it. If you already know it's not correct then take it out. No need to clutter.

```
protected virtual void UpdateObject(  SixenseInput.Controller controller )
{    
    z += 0.5f;
    m_initialPosition += new Vector3(0.0f,0.0f,z);
    this.gameObject.transform.position = m_initialPosition;
}
```

Then look for `controller.JoystickX` and/or `controller.JoystickY` <- this will give you the values you need. It took 2 minutes to search in Google which gives me the impression you didn't, the API should be included with the download for the Unity Plugin - I'd highly recommend reading it.

Comment: yeah i know that i took the joytick button state because i didn't found something that answer my question.. so thank you for your help i'll try it :)

Comment: http://u3d.as/content/sixense-studios/sixense-unity-plugin/4pA The plugin says it comes with examples - did you try those?